# How to forecast a time series out-of-sample using an ARIMA model in Python?

Tags: python, predict, arima, forecast

I have seen similar questions at Stackoverflow.  But, either the questions were different enough or if similar, they actually have not been answered.  I gather it is something that modelers run into often, and have a challenge solving.

In my case I am using two variables, one Y and one X with 50 time series sequential observations.  They are both random numbers representing % changes (they could be anything you want, their true value does not matter.  This is just to set up an example of my coding problem).  Here are my basic codes to build this ARIMAX(1,0,0) model.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/gaetanlion/Google Drive/Python/Arima/df.xlsx', sheet_name = 'final')

from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
endo = df['y']
exo = df['x']
```

Next, I build the ARIMA model, using the first 41 observations

```
modelho = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(endo.loc[0:40], exo.loc[0:40], order =(1,0,0)).fit()
print(modelho.summary())
```

So far everything works just fine.

Next, I attempt to forecast or predict the next 9 observations out-of-sample.  Here I want to use the X values over these 9 observations to predict Y.  And, I just can't do it.  I am showing below just the one code, that I think gets me the closest to where I need to go.

```
modelho.predict(exo.loc[41:49], start = 41, end = 49, dynamic = False)
TypeError: predict() got multiple values for argument 'start'
```

Answer (score 0):

This example should work. I am using your code but it is slightly changed.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
```

## generate an example data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x' : np.random.normal(12, 3,size = 332),
                     'y' : np.random.normal(12, 2,size = 332)})

df

endo = df['y']
exo = df['x']
```

### The order of Arima model kept as in your code, it is just for demonstration

#### Lets leave last 12 observations out of the model

```
modelho = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(endo[:-12], exo[:-12], order =(1,0,0)).fit()
modelho.summary()



future_x = exo[-12:]

modelho.predict(exog = future_x, start = 320, end = 331)
```

One can also use:

```
 modelho.forecast(12, exog = future_x)
```

Comment: I ran your exact codes.  They worked.  But, I have no idea why. When you code within the model ... exo[:-12]... this means you are deleting the 12th column and keeping all rows.  Yet, by doing that, you kept all columns and deleted 12 rows.  I don't understand how that code worked.  When you predict and you code ... exo[-12].  You take out the X values for the last 12 observations.  But, I want to keep the X information.  This is a Model Hold Out or out-of-sample testing, where I want to predict the last 12 Y values using the 12 X values and the Y t-1 autoregressive variable.

Comment: exo[:-12] means leave last 12 obs out of model. If you run endo[:-12] == endo.loc[0:319] and exo[-12:]==exo.loc[320:331] you will see these two syntax are slicing the data in same way. When exogenous variables are used in Arima their future values need to be provided for making a prediction that's why I left 12 obs out. if you do not have exog future value and they are both endogenous then I would suggest using VAR models. VAR will allow you to predict x and y jointly. I hope this helps.

Comment: More on VAR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression#:~:text=Vector%20autoregression%20(VAR)%20is%20a,allowing%20for%20multivariate%20time%20series.

Comment: i still do not understand why my original codes did not work.  I provide all the arguments or info necessary for the prediction.  And, I don't understand the ... got multiple values for argument 'start' ... when I just code ... start = 41.

Comment: @Sympa Please try modelho.forecast(9, exog = exo.loc[41:49])

Comment: I tried your codes, it got me results from the 9th observations to the 40th one using exogenous data from the 41st to the 49th observation input.  This did not make any sense.  So, instead of 9, I also tried inputting 41 to get me estimates from the 41st to the 49th (well really from the 42nd to 50th using Python counting).  But, that generated another error.

Comment: when you use 'modelho.forecast(12, exog = future_x)' it is not "results from the 9th observations to the 40th" it is 9 steps ahead forecast. see documentation '?modelho.forecast' . if the results are looking strange then you need to change the order of the Arima model. I am just providing a toy example that shows how one can produce a forecast (prediction). good luck :)